# uid Changing Depending on Method of Retrieval, iOS Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Why does using the method
`Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`
return a different uid than is returned by the completion during the
`Auth.auth().createUser` method when using Firebase Authentication with Swift 5? When I print them out they are different. My understanding is that the user should be assigned one unique userID and this should never change, throughout the database.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's not possible to tell if you might be doing something wrong. A user's uid never changes.

Comment: @DougStevenson so you mean that this should not occur? That theoretically they should be the same?

Comment: It's not a theory - it's a fact.  They would only be different if you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Okay. I am just trying to make sure I conceptually understand uids so that I know if my code is wrong or my concepts are.